# LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW on a win32 listview (common controls 6) returning 0

Tags: listview, winapi, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to get item groups working in a listview using VFP9.

```
#define LVM_FIRST               0x1000
#DEFINE LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW     LVM_FIRST + 157
#define LVM_ISGROUPVIEWENABLED  LVM_FIRST + 175

DECLARE LONG SendMessage IN win32api AS sendMyMessage;
    LONG HWND, INTEGER Msg, LONG wParam, INTEGER LPARAM

sendMyMessage(THIS.HWND, LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW,1,0)
```

This is always returning 0 and groups are not showing. Sending `LVM_ISGROUPVIEWENABLED` returns as well 0.

This is v6.0 (SP6) of the common controls (as confirmed by .aboutbox).

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you added any groups?

Comment: i have 2 groups added with 1 item each. They appear to being accepted (i.e. no errors from sendmessage). Are you suggesting only send LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW after the groups are added?
edit: tried that.. no difference.

Comment: Have you added items to the list before adding the groups? You can't add groups to an empty listview.

Comment: yes. I saw that in the MSDN documentation (but there are comments is sample code around the net that says is not so....)

Comment: AIUI the LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW should be sent before the groups are added (even before the items are added) and this should be returning 1 regardless of anything else??

Comment: I don't think that's the case. 1) Add items (even just one). 2) Add groups. 3) Enable group view whenever you want.

Comment: that is what i am doing.

Comment: test code adds an item then adds a group and then assigns the item to that group. But LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW always returns 0 (not even -1 to indicate failure) whether i issue before the items are added or after. Just adding diagnostics now and can see that my LVM_INSERTGROUP is also returning 0 which i could interpret as an index.... except that a subsequent LVM_GETGROUPCOUNT also returns 0.

Comment: This may or may not be relevant, but all arguments to `SendMessage` (except for `Msg`) need to be pointer-sized. I don't know what `LONG` maps to, but `INTEGER` is apparently a 32-bit value. I suppose there is no 64-bit version of VFP, so none of this may actually be an issue.